# Relate VSCode element color names with the screen location

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I've spent some trial and error time on this so if someone could even point me to a VSCode chart that shows the names of the element next to what they control it would be a great help.

It seems that this would be a common need for modifying VSCode color themes so I may just be missing something basic. You can't embarrass me so fire away even if everyone already knows how to do this.

There is a screenshot that should be showing up. The image is of VSCode with "workbench.colorCustomizations": {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are `panelTitle`'s (typically `Terminal`, `Output`, etc.):

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "panelTitle.activeForeground": "#ff0000",

  "panelTitle.inactiveForeground": "#00d9ff",

  "panelTitle.activeBorder": "#ff0000"   // an underline below the active one
}
```

whichever one is selected is the `active` one, of course.

This is the best source for element names for themes: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color but it only has a very few pictures, mostly text descriptions.

Comment: Thank you Mark! I spent a lot of time on the api/references page that you linked but I did not figure this out. I am surprised that there is no simple chart out there to make this easier.